# How can I convert scanned handwritten tables to Excel spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Until now, my grandparents handwrote their financial records, but their non-cursive handwriting is neater and more intelligible than the pictures beneath. After they scan each page, can Excel 2019 automatically and forthwith convert the scanned image to an Excel spreadsheet? Even if OCR recognizes the text and numbers, arranging each text and number will consume too much time.

[Here's the second picture's source](https://takingaccountproject.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/financial-records-of-wdb-part-3/). [This 2016 Reddit post](https://redd.it/3cgmng) yields nothing helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've used an OCR package (SharpDesk; not sure if it is still available) that came with a Sharp copier/scanner/printer. It did a pretty good job of converting a scan of columnar data to a format that Excel could ingest. Even so, there were errors, so we had to have employees review everything. But it was still faster than hand-entering the data. However, that was typed/printed images, not hand-written, like your example is. I suspect the accuracy with a hand-written source will be so low that it won't be worthwhile.

Comment: What is the benefit of scanning and then (invariably) manually correcting the data versus just typing in the data by hand? At the end of the day OCR can only do so much cleanly.

Comment: What version of Excel currently you are using,, coz recently on Twitter @msexcel handle I got a news that using latest version, handwritten Table can be converted into Spreadsheet !

Comment: @RajeshS Excel 2019

Comment: I'm sure 2019 has the feature to solve the issue,, check the Twitter handle and this also,, https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=JNfDR-Nx4Qc !

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal,, read this article https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2019/02/28/new-to-microsoft-365-in-february-advance-security-and-empower-a-modern-workplace/?utm_source=t.co&utm_medium=referral#excel

Comment: @JakeGould Doug did note that it was printed images that he was scanning in, where as long as the number of errors is low enough, checking for errors should be quicker than manual input, especially if you can add checks (such as making sure totals add up to the scanned total, where you then be sure the data is correct by checking one field)

Comment: @Baldrickk Doug is a commenter, not the original poster, so—honestly and sorry to be blunt—who cares? Of course printed grids and text are relatively easy to OCR. But the original poster is talking about handwritten text and that is what my comment is regarding. In my fully experienced opinion, if the text is handwriting OCR is useless and just data entry by hand is the best way to go.

Comment: @JakeGould agreed, sorry, I thought that you were replying to the comment above yours, as he was actually talking about OCR.

Comment: @RajeshS, those two links are very different.  The second one works with machine printing, not handwriting.  The first uses a capture pen rather than OCR.  Those pens capture information about the strokes used to create the characters, which is a much better source for guessing what the characters are.  A lot of preparation goes into the forms and their templates, so it's best suited to recurring entry of standard information.  (cont'd)

Comment: To be effective, users get trained in how to write for good recognition, the fields use data validation targets as much as possible, and the results are reviewed and corrected.  With a lot of prep and training, they can get decent results.

Comment: @fixer1234,, this I got from MSExcel,,,                           This feature is currently only available on our Android app: http://msft.social/TKJSnc . If you'd like to see it for a desktop, please add your suggestion to our UserVoice: http://msft.social/0tRhSh .

Comment: @RajeshS, it looks like a pretty neat idea.  It can only work with printed content, though, not handwriting.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal Did you try extracttable.com p.s: I contributed my time to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to agree with [music2myear’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1420645/167207).

#### With any computer to which you would have access, you can't do anything useful to go from handwritten records to Excel.

There are at least three difficult tasks:

1. Distinguishing "content" from non-content.
2. Recognizing the layout and translating that to cell locations.
3. Recognizing the handwritten characters and translating them to text.

Consumer software and online services are available and do a reasonable job of converting machine-printed text that is in clean table format to a spreadsheet file.  But even the best can be far from perfect.  That's just the task of assigning text to the right cell based on its position.

When you look at those images, your brain is very good at sorting out what is "preprinted form", what is content, what is noise, and what is human markings that aren't relevant.  You can recognize how things are aligned, and what goes with what based on context.  To the computer, everything that isn't the background color is "something".  Figuring out what of that is important to you, and what could potentially be some kind of character to be translated is extremely difficult.  And if the content overlaps preprinted lines, that introduces breaks and missing data that the computer can't easily handle.

Take your images, for example.  The first image is a lost cause.  Much of it ignores the lines and layout.  You would have the additional task of separating and removing the preprinted grid from the content.  In the second image, the content is mostly within the bounds of the grid, but there are lots of stray markings (slashes, underlines, etc.) that would require cleanup.

The toughest part, though, is recognizing handwriting and converting that to computer text.  For image 1, even humans would have trouble figuring out what some of that is, and it would involve a lot of guessing based on context and familiarity with the words.  In image 2, most of the numbers aren't too bad, but the text would be a problem.

If your grandparents' records are non-cursive, and neat, legible, consistent, and similar to machine printing, OCR might do a "reasonable" job on it.  But you would still have a lot of cleanup.

For perspective, the US Postal Service has some of the most advanced handwriting recognition, which it uses to read addresses on mailpieces so they can be sorted with automated equipment.  The only way they are able to do it is because the addresses are in a prescribed structure and format, and they know every possible address ahead of time.  The objective is more to match the handwritten addresses to viable candidates than to get every character right.

There is a ton of redundancy.  If you can only decipher half of the characters, there still may be only one or a few possible matches.  Even with that, a substantial portion requires human intervention.  When it's done and the mail gets to the carrier for delivery, the carrier knows the addresses and names on their route, and they check it all to ensure that the addresses weren't misinterpreted.

That's the level of handwriting OCR with state-of-the-art technology and an extremely controlled range of possibilities to compare against.  Your task needs to translate every character.  You don't have a master list of all the words that could legitimately be in those records (other than a dictionary of the entire language).  OCR would require so much cleanup that it would be faster to simply read the records and type them into Excel.  That's not an unusual task, and professional data entry people can do it pretty quickly and inexpensively.

Comment: No disrespect, but what does this answer add to the equation that music2myear’s answer does not already cover more succinctly and directly? I respect your posts on this site, but in this case I am not too sure how to interpret this answer.

Comment: @JakeGould It adds a lot of content and contextual information. More than is strictly necessary to answer the question, and way more than could be added in a comment, but it's helpful to answer any possible disagreements OP may have had believing my answer, which was more direct and succinct, but also left out a lot of additional information for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @JakeGould, I tried to get more specific with the "what" and "why" so readers have some context and a better understanding of the nature of the problem.  music2myear's answer comes to the right conclusion.  If the question was just, "can I do it, yes or no?", that answer would be plenty.  Putting myself in the OP's position, I would want to have a better understanding of what I was up against -- the nature of the problems, the potential to get the job done via additional available steps and processes beyond putting it through one piece of software, (cont'd)

Comment: and whether the state of capabilities was that a consumer solution might be just around the corner vs. nothing in the foreseeable future.  The question talks about the actual data being better quality than the posted images, suggesting the OP wants to understand what factors would make it better in a useful way, and how much difference could that make.  I tried to provide the flavor of that.  I also suggested looking at professional data entry people, which is a good solution that most people don't think of.  That was my objective, anyway.

Comment: @music2myear All fair! All good.

Answer (score 3):

## With this, you cannot.

Or, you can try using the tools that do this, called "OCR" (for "Optical Character Recognition"), however these are based on algorithms that make best guesses as to the characters that are being represented, and based on the condition of the inputs you have here, you're VERY UNLIKELY to get a satisfactory result.

Basically, even with the best tools available on the consumer and enterprise market today, you will end up having to manually correct or enter nearly all of the data yourself anyway.

Computers may be continually improving, but they remain far inferior to human eyes and brain in interpreting this sort of information, at least at the level of computer and software available to you and I.